# How to hide browserAction icon and show only on sites that match in content_scripts?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

My browser extension is always showing actionbar icon. But I want to browser_action displayed only on matches content scripts. Because my webextension   users not often use it, so i want to hide icon for dont  irritate they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pageAction, it can do what you want: hide and show when necessary. It will show in the address bar.

The functionality is very similar to a browserAction.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction